# bash script to run from multiple threads

Tags: bash, shell, curl, postman

I have a simple script that I wrote to perform api calls to a service of mine:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    curl -XGET 'https://myApiAddress/personSearch?name=John&country=DE' -k -H 'myLogin-token: SOME_TOKEN'
done
```

so this is a very basic script to call this api 10 times, but now I want to test my service and have this script perform 100 calls in a min, for 5 hrs, and if possible to have it do it from multiple threads...

I know there are tools for that like jmeter but I need to do something quick and only once, can someone help and tell me how is it possible to have my script do that? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using apache benchmark tool.

You need `apache2-utils` to be installed for `ab` to work.

> - -t duration in seconds
> - -v verbose prints response
> - -H to pass header
> - -c number of threads

```
ab -t 18000 -v -c 10 "https://myApiAddress/personSearch?name=John&country=DE" -H "myLogin-token: SOME_TOKEN"
```

Comment: didn't know ab has a `print response` mode, neat

Answer (score 1):

Bash not supports threading but you can use multiprocessing with background option.Also i recommend you to check crontab.İt is useful for this type of problems.